# How to run ultralight on Windows?

Tags: html, c++, cmake, linker, mingw

https://docs.ultralig.ht/docs/writing-your-first-app

I wanted to run demo app provided by ultralight.

I ran

```
git clone https://github.com/ultralight-ux/ultralight-quick-start
cd ultralight-quick-start
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

But last command gives 40 undefined reference errors.

First one of them:

```
CMakeFiles\MyApp.dir/objects.a(MyApp.cpp.obj):MyApp.cpp:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN10ultralight3App6CreateENS_8SettingsENS_6ConfigE'
```

How is that it doesn't work as it should?
I'm using gcc and g++ from MinGW given with CodeBlocks and I'm setting cmake to create CodeBlocks project.

Last command tries to compile the project and I thought it's all already set up to work properly but seems like it's not. I added all four files from ultralight-quick-start\build\SDK\lib\ (AppCore.lib, Ultralight.lib, UltralightCore.lib and WebCore.lib) to `Link libraries` in `Compiler settings` in CodeBlocks but the errors remain.

I guess ultralight is irrelevant and I just don't get how linker works but I can't overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `x64` Windows platform you should run build with next note:

`cmake .. -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64` instead of `cmake ..`

https://docs.ultralig.ht/docs/trying-the-samples